# How to find indexpath in collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I am developing player application. I have playlist and on collectionview there is a border which shows which song currently playing. When the song ends it automatically going on next song.

I want automatically update that cell as currentPlaying cell and reset previous cell as normal state.

For that reason I want find indexPath for current and previous played song.

```
func playingCompositionForReload(composition: Composition) {
        composition.isPlaying = true        
      // find index path and reload one cell only
}
```

How could I find it?

Comment: In my opinion you question is way too general

Comment: Create three variables of type IndexPath : currentlyPlaying,previouslyPlayed and nextPlayable. Everytime u update the currently playing song update all the three index paths in your VC.

Comment: If you ask a question, you should keep it updated with respect to whether you've found an answer or in fact used an answer which someone posted for you. Otherwise people will see in your history that you don't accept answers, & they'll stop answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep the current cell's indexPath in a var:

```
var currentlyActiveCellIndexPath: IndexPath
```

When the user selects a cell, set currentlyActiveCellIndexPath to that cell's indexPath (though this depends on how you start everything off - you may not need this if you start with the first cell automatically for instance, then you'd just set currentlyActiveCellIndexPath to IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) )

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.currentlyActiveCellIndexPath = indexPath
    // etc, etc
}
```

You'll need to implement some sort of delegate pattern (where the cell calls a method on its delegate) to let your controlling code know that the song has finished, & when it gets the call, just call the function you've created on the next cell, which you find by incrementing the indexPath's item. Eg -

```
// delegate method called by cell

func songDidFinish() {

    self.currentlyActiveCellIndexPath.item += 1

    // Obviously you'll have to use whatever class you've created your cells as here, with the relevant methods, etc.

    if let nextCell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.currentlyActiveCellIndexPath) as? SongPlayingCell {
        nextCell.startPlaying()
    }
}
```

Presumably, when a cell stops playing, it can set its own state.

If you're not sure about how to use delegates, that's another question, & there's plenty of info out there about that.